# Rounded dotted border with gradient

Tags: css

How to make rounded dotted border with gradient in CSS3? I found only borders with gradient and dotted borders separately. This is what I have to implement:
[image]

Comment: You would be better off using SVG for this instead of CSS.

Comment: Unfortunately, pure CSS, even CSS3, do not support gradient border that has rounded corners. If you want a quick solution, just use a PNG background image for the button or as Harry suggested, use SVG. SVG will look crisper. I made an example: http://codepen.io/Himechi90/pen/yOENKL

Comment: @Harry, OK, let me see) But I know how to do with SVG just making it as background-image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set a white dotted border on top of a gradient image covering only the border zone. It looks like your request

```css
.test {
  width: 300px;
  height: 80px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: dotted 10px white;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(white, white), linear-gradient(blue, magenta);
  background-origin: border-box;
  background-clip: content-box, border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

Comment: Happy that it helped you :-)

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily done with CSS3 .

```
<div class="greeting">Hello&Welcome</div>
```

And the corresponding css :

```
 .greeting{
        width:150px;
        height:100px;
        background-color:cyan;
        line-height:100px;
        color :white;
        text-align:center;
        border: 2px dotted black;
        border-radius:20px;
 }
```

Please find the code in codepen:
https://codepen.io/Debabrata89/pen/VadLMM

Hope this helps.

Comment: Borders should be with gradients)